# Rails Action Mailer async ECONNREFUSED localhost:25

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am testing out Action Mailer for the first time, attempting to configure a User Welcome email upon signup. I understand that an email will not actually be send in development mode, but the logs seem to be showing an error.

Upon creating a user, my logs look like [this](https://gist.github.com/m-delc/a49715fc723fe32b53fb1adab0806eb5). It appears that my email is created properly in both plain text and html, but after I see the error: `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:25)`

My User.create action:

```
    def create
    user = User.create(user_params)
    if user.valid?
        WelcomeMailer.welcome.deliver_later
        session[:current_user] = user.id
        return render json: user, status: 201
    else
        return render json: { error: user.errors.full_messages }, status: 404
    end
end
```

I have tried both `WelcomeMailer.welcome.deliver` and `WelcomeMailer.welcome.deliver_now` but they don't work either (although the errors are not related to async).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set action_mailer [configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail) for Gmail in your environment?

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true}
```

Take a look at the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) to have a better understanding of ActionMailer

Comment: I'm a beginner and so this is still unclear to me. In my project there is no file config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb, am I meant to create that file and then paste in what you typed?

Comment: what domain would I use instead of "example.com"?

Comment: For domain you can set gmail.com, but how did you create the project? `rails new project_name`? `development.rb` should be there by default. Also what are your ruby & rails versions? Follow the [beginners guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on how to create a new project from start.

Comment: Ahh, so by "$RAILS_ENV.rb" they mean "development.rb" or "production.rb", I see. That isn't obvious at all to a beginner. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, actually $RAILS_ENV is used es env variable to differentiate environments and run different configurations based on this. So, are you now able to send email?

Comment: I have just made it back to this project. I am not able to send emails and am pretty lost.